# Mysql DML Performance

Tags: mysql, performance

In my case I have a Mysql Table with 2,976,977 records. This table has indexes on two columns, and I used these two columns while updating and inserting records from multiple clients.  The problem is that it is taking too much time for updating or inserting the values.  Is any Idea to speed up this?

Comment: how frequent are the updates/inserts? how fast do you need them to be, and how fast are they now? is this about a single machine, or do you need to have the modifications available on a replication slave? what is your table structure like? what kind of storage engine are you using?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to profile the query execution plan

Comment: @haim: You can only generate EXPLAIN on SELECTs, not DML statements.

Comment: Actually I forgot to ask, what kind of updates/inserts....single rows, range of rows, bulk load?

Comment: @Roland Bouman: There are nearly 20000 updates and inserts will happen everyday.I am using "InnoDB Storage Engine".An update must finish within 30 sec,Now it is taking more than 1 min,and also the speed is decreasing Day by Day.

Comment: @Roland Bouman: yes,For Insertion it is multiple rows but for  update it  is single row.

Comment: Palani: So i get the impression it is mainly doing the 20000 update statments that is taking too long. Are you running the updates in autocommit mode (default)? if so, then you can improve performance a lot by doing:

START TRANSACTION;

...update statements go here...

COMMIT;

please note that if one of the updates does not succeed due to a constraint violation, you cannot COMMIT. And your data will not be stored permanently until you do COMMIT.

Comment: I am doing the update and insert by using JDBC transaction concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, i get the impression it is mainly doing the 20000 update statments that is taking too long. Are you running the updates in autocommit mode (default)? if so, then you can improve performance a lot by doing:

```
START TRANSACTION;
...update statements go here...
COMMIT;
```

please note that if one of the updates does not succeed due to a constraint violation, you cannot COMMIT. And your data will not be stored permanently until you do COMMIT.

In java, you could do something like:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, userName, passWord);
//explicit transaction by disabling autocommit.
conn.setAutocommmit(false);
java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

//add all your statements to the batch, f.e. in a loop
for (...) {
    stmt.addBatch(sql);
}

int results[] = stmt.executeBatch();
...check the results here...

//store results permanently in db
conn.commit();
```

Comment: I am doing the update and insert by using JDBC transaction concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Indexes may not make inserting and updating faster - they could make them slower because the indexes need to be updated.

Comment: Thanks,Long time back it was very slow and then I have created Indexes by referring Google  for that table it gets improved but now it getting slow day by day as record counts  are increased.

Comment: You may want to run ANALYZE TABLE to update statistics if your instance has been running for a while.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Yes, indexes do slow dml down. But seriously, doing 20000 updates should not be a big deal.

Comment: @Roland Bouman - I tend to agree.  ~3M rows isn't that many, either.  Seems like it must be something else.

Comment: @Roland Bouman:  I am doing the update and insert by using JDBC transaction concepts.